is't right in classic models find customers that have orderd most. I don't find customers that have ordered the same quantity
select productline, customerName, totale 
from(
    SELECT productLines.productline, 
         customers.customerName,
         sum(quantityOrdered) as totale 
    from customers, orders, productlines, products, orderdetails 
    WHERE customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber 
       and orderdetails.orderNumber= orders.orderNumber 
       and orderdetails.productCode = products.productCode 
       and productlines.productLine= products.productLine 
    GROUP by productlines.productline, customers.customerName 
    order by sum(quantityOrdered) desc 
   ) as lista 
group by productline;

in practice the query works well but I had to use a subquery which must give ordered results and in my opinion it doesn't work if there are two customers who have ordered the same number of pieces for the same type.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem. I tried with where total = (select but it gives me an error

Your query is non-deterministic and only working because you have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled. You shouldn't be using the archaic comma separated joins. Explicit joins are much easier to read, as the join criteria should be in the ON clause right next to the table name. What is it that your query does or does not do, compared to what you want it to do? If you want the top customer(s) for each productline you could use RANK().

I will use rank from now on I did not know him thank you very much

select * from
(
SELECT productLines.productline, customers.customerName, sum(quantityOrdered) as totale1 from customers, orders, productlines, products, orderdetails WHERE                                    customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber and orderdetails.orderNumber= orders.orderNumber and orderdetails.productCode = products.productCode and                                      productlines.productLine= products.productLine
GROUP by productline , customerName
) as a
left join
(

SELECT productLines.productline, customers.customerName, sum(quantityOrdered) as totale1 from customers, orders, productlines, products, orderdetails WHERE                                    customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber and orderdetails.orderNumber= orders.orderNumber and orderdetails.productCode = products.productCode and                                      productlines.productLine= products.productLine
GROUP by productline , customerName
) as b
on a.productline = b.productline  and  a.totale1 < b.totale1
where  isnull(b.totale1);
ok resolved

While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

As I stated in my comment above, your query is non-deterministic and only working because you have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled. Bill gives a nice simple explanation of the problem with MySQL's behaviour with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled here. You can read more in the docs - MySQL Handling of GROUP BY
Assuming you just want the top customer(s) for each productline you can use GROUP BY and RANK():
SELECT productLine, customerName, totale
FROM (
    SELECT pl.productLine, c.customerName,
        SUM(quantityOrdered) AS totale,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY pl.productline ORDER BY SUM(quantityOrdered) DESC) AS rnk
    FROM customers c
    JOIN orders o
        ON c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
    JOIN orderdetails od
        ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
    JOIN products p
        ON od.productCode = p.productCode
    JOIN productlines pl
        ON pl.productLine = p.productLine
    GROUP BY pl.productline, c.customerName
) AS lista
WHERE rnk = 1;


This post is hidden. You deleted this post just now.
I understood that I have to use rank
What do you think of the solution with left join and control a.total<b.total?

Hidden? I deleted what? Test the different solutions and see what does or doesn't work for you. Make sure you test against a suitably representative dataset.
